# How do i get google cse to just search images

Tags: google-custom-search

Google's Custom search engine is really good. Though im having problems with it. Whenever i search on it, it has 2 tabs. (Web and Image). How do i get it to have the image tab to be the default tab when something is searched.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use "defaultToImageSearch" param in your search box configuration:

It is explained here:
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element#supported_attributes